# recording durations in milliseconds using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building an AJAX page that when the user clicks a box, it sends an ajax request and returns a result.  This is a very simple game.  The users repeatedly click the box, and I need to record how much time has elapsed between each click with a precision of milliseconds.  So with my request actually, I will be sending the elapsed time since the last request and storing it in a database or session.

Javascript does have a timer that is precise in ms, right?  So does jQuery make this task of keeping a time between clicks easy?

Comment: Don't know if this will make a difference, but depending on how you record this, you'll have no guarantee that click 1 will hit your server before click 2.

Comment: good point, I'll have to disable the ability to click until I get a return response.  It is turn-based so that's ok.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need jQuery for this. To get the time on the user's machine in milliseconds:

```
var nowInMilliseconds = new Date().getTime();
```

And so to compare two times, just subtract the start time from the end time, and that's the difference in milliseconds.

Example:

```
(function() {
    var firstClick;

    function clickHandler() {
        var now, duration;

        now = new Date().getTime();
        if (!firstClick) {
            // Remember the time of the first click
            firstclick = now;
        }
        else {
            // Second click; how long as it been?
            duration = now - firstClick;

            // Reset so we're waiting for the first click again
            firstClick = undefined;

            // ...send your Ajax data to the server...
        }
    }

    function pageLoad() {
        $('#button').click(clickHandler);
    }

    window.onload = pageLoad; // or jQuery.ready() or whatever
})();
```

(The outer function is just for scoping, so we don't create unnecessary global symbols.)

Comment: Thanks, or in my case, subtract it from the last time to get the difference between events.  I'll probably wrap it with jQuery event handling still.

Comment: You subtract the first time from the second, not the second from the first. Otherwise you end up with a negative number. :-)

Comment: Oh now that's funny, we *both* said it backward. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Shorter alternative to `new Date().getTime()`: `+new Date`

Comment: @J-P: LOL! I actually typed a parenthetical about that (e.g., as a "l33t" alternative but needing a big comment explaining it -- such as the one in Google Closure), but then decided it was too much information.